# Use search terms from awk to grep and output to separate search term specific files

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I have a bunch of search terms generated through awk - a uuid per line.

I want to grep an input file for each of these uuid's and output to separate output files for each uuid.

Eg:

```
awk.output:
uuid1
uuid2
uuid3

file.input:
this is uuid1
this is uuid2
this is uuid3

desired files -
uuid1.output:
this is uuid1

uuid2.output:
this is uuid2

uuid3.output:
this is uuid3
```

What is a concise way of doing this without any shell scripting? Like just use awk, grep and redirect operations.

Comment: just `awk` is enough.

Comment: Please add your attempt in question

Answer (score 0):

May not work for special inputs... :D

```
xargs -a awk.input -d "\n" -I {} sh -c 'grep "${1}" file.input > "${1}.output"' -- {}
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` can append to files using

```
print items >> output-file
```

so, you can have something like

```
awk 'FILENAME == "awk.output" {uuids[$1]++} FILENAME != "awk.output" { for (u in uuids) { if ($0 ~ u) {print  >> (u ".output")}}} ' awk.output file.input
```